# What is /tmp/jetty-docbase directory used for

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using SpringBoot and Embedded Jetty.

I see it creates directory /tmp/jetty-docbase...

What is this directory used for? how can I change the root path of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the document root; the location from which static files will be served by Jetty (rather than by Spring MVC's static resource handling). Spring Boot tries the following locations in order, stopping its search as soon as it finds a match:

1. An explicitly configured location (`ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.setDocumentRoot()`)
2. The `.war` file if running from an executable war
3. The root directory of an exploded war (identified by the presence of a `WEB-INF` directory)
4. `./src/main/webapp`
5. `./public`
6. `./static`
7. `$TMP_DIR/jetty-docbase`

In your case it's reached 7. This location is used as Jetty needs some location for its document root even if its empty.

If you want to explicitly control the location used for the document root you can configure it by declaring a `JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean:

```
@Bean
public JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyFactory() {
    JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.setDocumentRoot(new File("custom/document/root"));
    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create folder ./public or ./static then springboot will never create temp jetty-docbase folder for you